# Serverless: WARNING: Inappropriate call of provider.request()

Tags: serverless-framework

I'm using Serverless & the Serverless-Finch plugin to deploy a Serverless website to S3.  Serverless Finch config is below.

```
custom:
  client:
    bucketName: my-site-${self:provider.stage}
    distributionFolder: build
    indexDocument: index.html
    errorDocument: index.html
```

When I run `serverless client deploy` the deployment is successful and my site is online hosted on S3, however the logs in the terminal show this warning repeated about 30 times.

```
Serverless: WARNING: Inappropriate call of provider.request()
```

I've tried searching for the cause/meaning of this warning but haven't been able to find any info, any help explaining the error meaning or pointing me to the right bit of documentation is much appreciated.

I've tried changing my YML to not take the stage from the provider object for the bucketName however the warning persisted so I know that is not the source of the issue.

Comment: I have now also raised this as a bug on the serverless-finch github, check there for possible updates: https://github.com/fernando-mc/serverless-finch/issues/45

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is due to us using the old provider API. We're fixing this in the next release.

https://github.com/fernando-mc/serverless-finch/pull/42

Disclosure - I'm the maintainer for this project.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Fernando, I haven't had a chance to test it with the latest release yet but will let you know when I do.  Cheers